# How did people stay/change to level 1 but their units are not level 1?

Tags: clash-royale

I wish I was smart enough to have taken a screenshot but I didn't.  Will do so next time I see this.  In Clash Royale, there were some replays shown on TV Royale where the player was level 1 but:

1. They were fighting in Arena 5 or 6
2. Their units were not level 1 and
3. Those units were found in arenas higher than Arena 1

I'm just curious, how did this happen or why did the game let this happen?  This was the craziest thing I saw within the game and I saw it at least 3 times on replays.

Comment: It was likely a bug with TV Royale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> They were fighting in Arena 5 or 6

They won enough trophies to reach these Arenas.

> Their units were not level 1

You can upgrade cards past level 1 and as long as your total xp earned from doing so remains less than 20 your king tower level will remain at level 1.

> Those units were found in arenas higher than Arena 1

They won enough trophies to reach the Arenas in which these cards were unlocked from chests or purchased from the shop.

Comment: @ crescentfresh, So basically, they didn't donate any cards, they didn't upgrade any cards, and they didn't collect exp/gems from the achievements so they could stay at lvl 1.  Why would someone do this?  They did this as a challenge to themselves?  To see how many ppl they can beat while they are lvl 1 while their opponents are several lvls higher?

Comment: @Classified: they cannot donate because they are not permitted to join a clan until King Tower Level 3, and they would upgrade cards only to the point of staying under 20 xp points. The reason for this is as you say, plus apparently it gets you on to TV Royale frequently.

Comment: Additionally, spawners such as buildings and the witch spawn units greater than level 1 even at level 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to upgrade the first cards you get. I currently have a level one account in arena 7 but I wasn't smart enough to upgrade  a common to level 4 like zap. Instead I accepted achievements for gems and now I have 19 out of 20 experience

Comment: I started a level 1 account to go for the record. I saw the guy with the level one in arena five and said hey I can beat that. You can find me on royale TV frequently as an added bonus. My account name is /\/\/-\><